# Correct punctuation of interposed examples

Tags: punctuation, comma

I'm a bit confused where I should put the commas when interposing examples which specifies the subject of the sentence as shown in the following sentence.

> Verwaltende und organisatorische Aufgaben, wie die Erfassung des Posteingangs und -ausgangs sowie der direkte Kontakt zu Mandanten und Behörden, sind wesentliche Bestandteile meiner Tätigkeit.

Is this usage correct?

Comment: As you see from the two totally conflicting answers, your question is quite good :) Don't know where the unnecessary close vote is from.

Comment: @OregonGhost Haven't raised that vote but since this vote states "too localized" I guess it's about as the question stands right now there's no obvious benefit to everyone. I amended the question.

Comment: A generalization of this question would have similar answers.

Comment: Ich würde es nicht so schreiben, sehe aber nicht viel Sinn darin darüber zu diskutieren, wo die amtlichen Regeln keine Regelpräzidenz vorgeben, denn Auslegung ist generel subjektiv, wilkürlich, und gehört nicht hierher. Sinnvoll wäre es ggf. nur um Zweideutigkeit zu vermeiden, dann würde ich aber nahelegen, den Satz umzuschreiben. Was hier nicht der Fall ist. Insofern sind die Kommas zumindest unnötig. In anderen, syntaktisch schwierigeren Beispielen mag das anders sein. Solches gatten wir vor wenigen Wochen. I call duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer**

[Rule § 78.2](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/pgf71-79.html#pgf78) is the answer to your question. You can place the comma or not. It's just a matter of style.

> § 78 Oft liegt es im Ermessen des Schreibenden, ob er etwas mit Komma als Zusatz oder Nachtrag kennzeichnen will oder nicht.
>
> […]
>
> Ihre Ausgaben(,) wie Fahrt- und Übernachtungskosten(,) werden Ihnen ersetzt.

---

**Elaborated discussion**

There are a couple of instances in which you must not place a comma.

1. If *wie* introduces a coordinate conjunction ("nebengeordnete Konjunktion") and *wie* can be replaced with, for example, the conjunction *and* the comma is **not** used.

   > Sowohl Hunde wie Katzen sind als Haustiere sehr beliebt. (= Hunde und Katzen sind als Haustiere sehr beliebt.)
2. If *wie* initiates a comparison the comma is **not** used, since it is not a subordinate clause.

   > Du bist dumm wie Stroh.

   More examples are given in [Takkat's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5699/correct-punctuation-of-interposed-examples/5701#5701)

If, however, a complete subordinate clause ("vollständiger Nebensatz") is initiated the comma is mandatory (even if the subordinate clause is a comparison):

> Ich habe keine Ahnung, wie er das angestellt hat.
>
> Sie irrten quer durch die Stadt, wie wenn keiner wusste, wo man denn hinwollte.
>
> Er ist genau so dumm, wie man es von einem Waldorfschüler erwartet.

Additionally there are some use cases in which the comma is recommended but not necessary:

- shorted subordinate clause ("verkürzter Nebensatz"),

  > Verwende(,) wie bereits erwähnt(,) keine Fachausdrücke.
- infinitive clause ("erweiterter Infinitiv"),

  > Er versprach uns(,) so schnell wie möglich nach Hause zu kommen.
- postpositive explanations ("nachgestellte Angaben") which aren't necessary for the understanding.

  > Nahrungsmittel(,) wie unser täglich Brot(,) sind seit jeher ein kostbares Gut.

The latter point I introduced fits in OP's example. The inserted part lists some instances which specifies the subject but aren't necessary for the understanding. Therefore the comma *can* be placed, but you don't need to. The comma correlates the pause in spoken language.

---

As noted in comments, it is advisable to put the comma in almost all cases where it is optional, since it increases readability. The infinitive clause example I've given may raise some confusion because *so* is also an adverb and the reader might expect a different end, such as:

> Er versprach uns so viele Dinge und hielt keines seiner Versprechen ein.

Comment: +1. Won't repeat my comment to the other answer here ;)

Comment: `Additionally there are some use cases in which the comma is recommended but not necessary: [...] infinitive clause ("erweiterter Infinitiv")[:]  Er versprach uns(,) so schnell wie möglich nach Hause zu kommen.` That's **crazy**. Who writes these things? Of course you must put a comma there. Thank you for another illustration of the pitfalls of taking canoo.net, wiktionary (or even Duden, for that matter) as gospel.

Comment: @Em1 LOL welches "Amt" hat das denn verordnet? Wusste gar nicht, dass es ein Amt für Zeichensetzung gibt! Das ist übrigens ein weiteres Beispiel dafür, was hier in german.SE kaputt ist. Zu viele IT-Fachleute, die meinen, Duden wäre so etwas wie Kernigan/Ritchie. Auch wenn diese Mitteilung euch jetzt wie ein Hammer vor den Kopf trifft: in natürlicheh Sprachen sind nicht zuerst die Regeln da und dann die Sprech- und Schreibakte, es ist umgekehrt. Um einen Disput zu klären, genügt kein "Blick ins Regelwerk". Man muss schon den guten Sprechern und Schreibern aufs Maul bzw. den Griffel schauen.

Comment: ... und ob das Extrahieren von Regeln aus der Sprache nun von einem "Amt", einem Blogger oder dem Pabst vollzogen wird, ist ganz egal. Es sind immer Menschen, und Menschen machen Fehler.

Comment: @Em1 Sie haben mich nicht verstanden. `Er versprach uns so`: Ein Satz, der so beginnt, könnte nach Erwartung des Lesers z.B. folgendermaßen weitergehen: `viele Dinge und machte keines seiner Versprechen wahr`. Wenn der Satz aber mit `schnell wie möglich nach Hause zu kommen` endet, springt das Auge des Lesers verwirrt zurück und sucht nach dem übersehenen Komma. Das Komma aber fehlt, denn die Schreiberin hat es vergessen, oder ihr mangelt es an Sprachgefühl, oder sie hat sich durch irgendein bombastisch so genanntes "amtliches Regelwerk" verunsichern lassen. Es bleibt ihr Fehler.

Comment: @Em1 Dem Wunsch, meine Kommentare zu löschen, bin ich schon einmal nachgekommen, habe es hinterher bereut. Dieses Mal lasse ich sie stehen. Wie wäre es, versuchsweise eine ganze Woche lang in german.SE auf das Zitieren von "amtlichen" oder nicht-amtlichen Regelwerken, mitsamt ihrer elenden, papierenen "Beispiele", zu verzichten? Und stattdessen aus dem reichen Fundus der schönen deutschen Sprache, in Form von Gedichten und Romanen, eleganter Wissenschaftssprache und gutem Journalismus, zu schöpfen?

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: Bitte stelle doch eine neue Frage zu dem Thema, ob eine amtliche Regel sinnvoll ist oder nicht. Dann kann man das viel besser diskutieren als in einem hier heillos unübersichtlichen Kommentarwust.

Comment: @ Eugene: Regeln versuchen zu ordnen, was sonst zwangsläufig zerfransen würde... streckenweise bis zur Unkenntlichkeit. Das ist mit allen Regeln so. Sonst wären es ja Naturgesetze. Wenn der Fragesteller wissen will, ob etwas korrekt ist, dann will er wissen ob es regelkonform ist. Wenn es nur nach persönlichem Eindruck ginge, müsste er das nicht Fragen. Was du hier als Regelreiterei verteufelst ist einfach nur ein Verweis auf den aktuellen offiziellen Stand. Was ist daran so, furchtbar? Ich habe das Komma mal gesetzt denn mir, kommt es richtig vor.

Comment: Diese zwei letzten Kommas suggerieren ironischerweise eine passende Betonung (mow).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's correct.

The part "*wie die Erfassung des Posteingangs und -ausgangs sowie der direkte Kontakt zu Mandanten und Behörden*" is an attributive clause ("Attributsatz" or "Beifügung") and has to be separated from the sentence in which it is embedded by commata.

This special attributive clause is built from two parts ("*wie die Erfassung des Posteingangs und -ausgangs*" and "*der direkte Kontakt zu Mandanten und Behörden*") that are linked together by the word "sowie". "Sowie" is a conjunction ("Konjunktion" or "Satzverbinder") that links two sentences together to one longer sentence, without a comma.

Comment: Are you sure ??? Do you have a reference for it? I mean it sounds logical but based on your argumentation THIS should be correct too:    Erwachsene Männer, wie ich oder mein Bruder, trinken gern ein Bier.    and that doesn't seem right to me... hwoever, the difference between both examples is but the lengths of the apposition

Comment: @Emanuel: Your example is correct. If you think you example was wrong, so what do you think was the correct version? And why do you think you example was wrong?

Comment: I would put no comma there unless I specifically want it to sound as a last minute appendix to what I am saying. reading out loud, I would probably be confused by the commas there... I might be wrong but I'd like to see a source

Comment: http://www.kidsnet.at/insp_deutsch/attribut.htm oder auch hier, Regel R3: http://www.brg-schoren.ac.at/wiki/5i/index.php?title=Zeichensetzung&redirect=no Auch das ist eine gute Quelle: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Attribut/index.html Noch mehr findest du hier: http://www.google.at/search?q=attributsatz+beistrich

Comment: I don't think this is an attributive clause. The Canoo sample you linked to does not indicate that. The rule R3 you linked is totally different. The first link also does not indicate that this is an attributive clause. Sorry, but I don't think you're right. The commas may be sensible since the sentence is relatively long, but they are not mandatory (or rather, should not be there).

Comment: @Emanuel: Your example sentence is, as you intended, wrong.

Comment: @OregonGhost (and Emanuel): The example sentence is correct as I pointed out in my answer. *Mein Bruder und ich* are two instances and *wie* is equally with *zum Beispiel*. You can place a comma or not: *Erwachsene Männer(,) wie mein Bruder und ich(,) trinken gerne Bier.* Whenever you would insert a pause while speaking you should place a comma.

Comment: @Em1: Didn't know that rule, actually. The commas in sentences like that always interrupt the flow, in my opinion. But as you explained very well, the sentence is also correct without comma, and that's how I would write it, especially when it's so short. I also think that the choice of writing (or not) the commas may make a subtle difference in how the sentence is understood. With commas (pauses), this emphasizes the middle thing, without commas, it does not.

Comment: @OregonGhost In German, commas are used (very) differently than in English (where intonation plays a huge role), so that to people who read and write a lot in English, the "German" way of using them might appear wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The correctness of the sentence depends on its interpretation:

#### Interpretation 1:

The author considers that each of the following activities is an example of *Verwaltende und organisatorische Aufgaben*.

If the author had omitted the examples, he/she would have written:

> Verwaltende und organisatorische Aufgaben sind wesentliche Bestandteile meiner Tätigkeit.

If this interpretation is correct, the punctuation is correct.

#### Interpretation 2:

The author wanted to express that *Kontakt zu Mandanten und Behörden* is an additional task besides *Verwaltende und organisatorische Aufgaben*.

The corresponding example-less sentence:

> Verwaltende und organisatorische Aufgaben sowie der direkte Kontakt zu Mandanten und Behörden sind wesentliche Bestandteile meiner Tätigkeit.

In that case I would have written:

> Verwaltende und organisatorische Aufgaben, wie die Erfassung des Posteingangs und -ausgangs, sowie der direkte Kontakt zu Mandanten und Behörden sind wesentliche Bestandteile meiner Tätigkeit.

Answer (score 0):

### [Subordinate clause of same range](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Komma/Aufzaehlung.html)

In your example *"wie"* initiates a coordinate subordinate clause. Hence the verb was omitted because it is identical with the main clause (*"...sind"*). Then, according to the [Offcial Rule §72](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/pgf71-79.html#pgf72-E1)  we do **not** set a comma:

> - **§ 72** Sind die gleichrangigen Teilsätze, Wortgruppen oder Wörter durch und, oder, beziehungsweise/bzw., sowie (= und), wie (= und), entweder ... oder, nicht ... noch, sowohl ... als (auch), sowohl ... wie (auch) oder durch weder ... noch verbunden, so setzt man kein Komma. <sup>[Amtliche Rechtschreibung](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/pgf71-79.html#pgf72-E1)</sup>

Let me give an example of this construction in a simple sentence where it becomes more obvious that we do not have a comma here:

> Eine Grammatik wie unsere ist schwer.
>   Satzbau wie Zeichensetzung finde ich schwierig.

In the given example, where the subordinate clause is quite long and the relations are unclear, we may however decide that we do need a comma to clarify (see [answer on §78](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5699/correct-punctuation-of-interposed-examples/5702#5702)):

> 1. Verwaltende und organisatorische Aufgaben, wie die Erfassung des Posteingangs und -ausgangs sowie der direkte Kontakt zu Mandanten und Behörden, sind wesentliche Bestandteile meiner Tätigkeit.
>
>    - *Both, mail management, and personal contacts are part of the organizational or administrative tasks. This is only correct when we believe that having personal contacts is indeed an element of our administrative or organizational responsibilities.*
> 2. Verwaltende und organisatorische Aufgaben(,) wie die Erfassung des Posteingangs und -ausgangs, sowie der direkte Kontakt zu Mandanten und Behörden sind wesentliche Bestandteile meiner Tätigkeit.
>
>    - *With this variant me make clear, that external contacts, and administrative tasks are different things. Mail management is now only an example given for the organizational tasks. Note that the first comma is **optional**.*
> 3. Verwaltende und organisatorische Aufgaben wie die Erfassung des Posteingangs und -ausgangs sowie der direkte Kontakt zu Mandanten und Behörden sind wesentliche Bestandteile meiner Tätigkeit.
>
>    - *Leaving out all commas is not against the rules (it also avoids setting a comma before "sowie") but depending on what we wanted to say it may be less clear as it was in versions 1 or 2. If however we want to put all subjects "administration", "organization", "mail", and "contacts" on the same level of importance it may be the best option.*

Comment: No, it's not a comparative clause. Not every subordinate clause  that starts with "wie" is a comparative clause. Quote from your source: "Ein Vergleichsatz (Komparativsatz) vergleicht die Aussage des Nebensatzes mit der Aussage des Hauptsatzes." In P3trus's sentence is no comparison of two statements. The subordinate clause in this sentence gives us just a more detailed description of the noun "Aufgaben". And this conforms exactly to the definition of an attributive clause. So, there must be commata!

Comment: We can fight endless whether *wie* is a comparative or not. But the rule is the same. We do **not** have a comma here. See my edit, help it is more clear.

Comment: I think rule 72 is the right one here. You could omit the "Verwaltende und organisatorische Aufgaben", so the sentence would start with "Die Erfassung des Posteingangs...", and it would still say basically the same. The first part is just a generalization.